# Can the electrolytes be in gaseous state?

Tags: ions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will gaseous ionic compounds be free moving ions?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/will-gaseous-ionic-compounds-be-free-moving-ions)

I know it sounds extremely expensive, but what if we could heat the ionic compound to evaporate it and achieve the lattice energy and break them into free ions, wouldn't the electrolysis be faster, as the ions can move faster freely than in liquid state?