# What is Sodium Chloride like in gas state?

Tags: physical-chemistry, ionic-compounds

Since sodium chloride is sodium and chlorine atoms bonded as a lattice and there are no discrete molecules, doesn't that mean in gas state, sodium chloride is simply sodium and chlorine atoms separate from each other, resulting in a mixture of sodium gas and chlorine gas?

Comment: See [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/will-gaseous-ionic-compounds-be-free-moving-ions/) for previous answers on the subject.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, in the gas phase sodium chloride exists as a monomer (the sodium chloride molecule) along with its dimer $\ce{Na2Cl2}$.  The dimer has a roughly rectangular shape and is quite floppy with chlorines located diagonally across from each other.  The dimer makes up about 27% of the mix.  All of the bond lengths, etc. can be found in [this thesis](https://www.era.lib.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/1842/2601/2/McCaffrey%20PD%20thesis%2007.pdf).  Go to the end and you'll see the full paper that appeared in JACS with all of the data.

Also [this paper here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp073328o)  (credit to orthocresol for finding that).  The abstract mentions "the equilibrium structures of the monomer (NaCl) and the dimer $\ce{Na2Cl2}$"

Comment: Very interesting source. To be clear, the equilibrium proportion of ionic monomers, dimers and larger aggregates varies with certain parameters, most notably temperature and pressure; high temperatures and low pressures favour more extensive dissociation into smaller units. From a quick look at the thesis, it would seem that the 1:0.27 molar proportion of the monomer and dimer was experimentally determined at $\rm{943\ K}$ for sodium chloride (which also suggests the measurements were made at a very low pressure). The proportion might be quite different for boiling salt at $\rm{1\ atm}$.

Comment: @Nicolau Saker Neto  Good point, thanks for adding it.

Comment: @ron Does this imply that all ionic compounds in gas phase are found as monomers and dimers?

Comment: I dunno, my guess would be many do, many don't.  I think some you'd need to heat so hot to get them vaporized they might exist as a plasma, others might decompose - but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Roughly, somewhere around half of the lattice enthalpy of a salt comes solely from the binding of the smallest electrically neutral agglomerate; that is, it takes about as much energy to break a macroscopic solid $\ce{NaCl}$ crystal into a gas of ion pairs as it does to break all the ion pairs and create a true plasma. Thus, it is rather unlikely that, at reasonable temperatures, an ionic gas will break down any further than the smallest possible electrically neutral aggregates.