# Ionic compound gases

Tags: ionic-compounds

Does any molecule containing only ionic bonds exist as a gas in room temperature? In the case of carbon dioxide, it is a covalent molecule which is a gas at rtp. Does the same apply for ionic compounds?

Comment: Hydrogen chloride is a covalent compound that reacts with water (and plenty of other compounds) to form ions.

Comment: That depends on your definition of an ionic bond...

Comment: If anything, being a gas in ambient conditions is a very strong argument *against* a compound being ionic.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/will-gaseous-ionic-compounds-be-free-moving-ions http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14174/what-is-sodium-chloride-like-in-gas-state